# Does 'we got each other' have the same meaning as 'we got each other's backs'?

Tags: meaning, phrase-usage

To *[have someone's back](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/have-someone-s-back)* means to "always be ready to defend or help someone."

So by extension, "we got each other's backs" is a way of saying that you and another person are both ready to defend and help one another in times of need.

What I want to know is whether "we got each other's backs" can be shortened to “we got each other” without changing the meaning.

The reason I wonder this is that "I got you” has the same meaning “I got your back.” Can this shortening be extended to the other phrase as well?

Comment: Welcome to ELU. It's not clear what you want to know here. Do you mean "How does *got your back* become the whole body in *got you*?" or do you want a list of circumstances in which the expression might be used? The first seems trivial, the second is not suited to Stack Exchange's "best answer" model. If you [edit] your question to make it clearer, it may be able to be re-opened.

Comment: "I got you" doesn't mean the same thing as "I got your back," as far as I know.

Comment: @alphabet - semantically it doesn't, technically it doesn't, but oftentimes it does in practice. As a younger speaker, I hear and use them as being synonymous, particularly when pronounced as "_I gotch you_." (as in: _relax, bro, I gotch you. don't worry_ )

Comment: @Heartspring "I got you" can *sometimes* mean "I got your back," but not always. "I'll pay for dinner." "No, I got you."

Comment: "We've got each other" is often used to mean "We're romantically connected".

Answer (score 0):

This expression does exist in pop culture, for instance a song by R&B artist Chaka Kahn:

> Walkin' hand and hand
> As only lovers can
> You must understand
> We've got each other
> They can scream and fuss
> It won't bother us
> And that is because
> We've got each other

https://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/chakakhan/wegoteachother.html

The meaning in these lyrics is both figurative and literal, but the figurative sense of “got your back” against adversity is present in the sense of supporting each other even though others “scream and fuss”

I don’t know to what extent it’s in common usage in AAVE in a purely figurative sense, but for what it’s worth, as a native English speaker (Canada/USA) I had no trouble parsing the meaning intended by “we got each other” and context would make the meaning evident.

The following link, for example, uses the term in reference to meetings designed for “young black men to come together” to support each other:

https://www.bgsu.edu/multicultural-affairs/resources/support-groups/we-got-each-other

Comment: *but the figurative sense of “got your back” against adversity is certainly present* You don't provide any evidence of this. Why is it impossible that only the literal meaning was intended?

Comment: Perhaps “certainly” is too strong, but the implication is that they have each other under adverse conditions, are therefore supporting each other (having each other’s back) despite others who “scream and fuss”

Comment: "We got each other" is also the punchline of the song "[Two Lost Souls](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C4iQ5Z313TI)" from _Damn Yankees_ (1958).